# z.infer<T> infers dynamic fields are required even if required prop is false

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

Environment:

- zod v. 3.22.4
- TypeScript v. 4.9.5

I have this props

```js
interface Props {
  additional_questions?: Question[]
}
```

Question is this type

```js
type TextQuestion = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  type: "text";
  value: string;
  required?: boolean;
};
```

The property additional_questions is

```js
[
 {
  id: 1, 
  title: "Idade", 
  value: "", 
  type: "text", 
  required: false 
 }
]
```

I have this zod form scheme

```js
const formSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().email("E-mail inválido"),
    names: z.string().min(1, "Campo obrigatório"),
    surnames: z.string().min(1, "Campo obrigatório"),
    phonenumber: z.string(),
    attendance: z.enum(["yes", "no"], {
      required_error: "Precisa de selecionar se aceita ou não o convite.",
    }),
    message: z.string(),
    additional_questions: z.array(
      z.object({
        id: z.number(),
        answer: z.string().min(1),
        title: z.string(),
        type: z.string(),
        required: z.boolean()
      })
    ),
  });
```

and this is the form:

```js
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      names: "",
      surnames: "",
      phonenumber: "",
      attendance: "yes",
      message: "",
      additional_questions: props.additional_questions
    },
  });
```

And this is the render section:

```js
{props.additional_questions && props.additional_questions?.map((question, index) => (
  <FormField
    key={question.id}
    control={form.control}
    name={`additional_questions.${question.id}.id`}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <FormItem>
        <FormLabel>{question.title}:</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
          {
            question.type == "text" ? <Input disabled={loading} {...field} /> :
              question.type == "textarea" ? <TextArea rows={5} disabled={loading}  {...field} /> :
                <div></div>
          }

        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage />
      </FormItem>
    )}
  />
))}
```

I don't know why when I try to submit the form all the additional questions are required even if the props.additional_questions has questions with required a false.

Can you help me?

I've have tried add `.optional()` in the schema and it stills requiring me the additional_questions.